# $(0 \leq f' \leq f$ on $\mathbb R$ and $f(a)=0)$ $\implies f=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Given that $0 \leq f' \leq f$  on $\mathbb R$  and $f(a)=0\in\mathbb R$ for some $a\in\mathbb R$, how do I prove that $f$ is identically zero?  Using the mean value theorem naively didn't really get me anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f'\ge 0$, then 
$$
f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^x f'\ge 0 \mbox{ for any } x>a
$$
For the other side,
$$
f'-f\le0 
$$
Then
$$
0\ge e^{-t}[\,f'-f\,]=(e^{-t}f)'
$$
Therefore
$$
e^{-x}f(x)=e^{-a}f(a)+\int_a^x (e^{-t}f(t))'\le 0 \mbox{ for any } x>a
$$
So, for $x>a$, $0\le f(x)\le 0$.

For $x<a$ same idea.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Suppose $a + 1 > x > a$. Then

$$f(x) = f(x) - f(a) = f'(c)(x-a)$$

For some $c \in (a,x)$. But

$$f'(c)(x-a) \leq f(c)(x-a) = (f(c) - f(a))(x-a) = f'(d)(c-a)(x-a)$$

For some $d \in (a,c)$. Suppose $f'$ is bounded by $M$ on $[a-1,a+1]$ (note that $f'$ is bounded on this set since $f$ is continuous so bounded on a compact set, and $f' \leq f$). Then

$$0 \leq f(x) \leq M (x-a)^{n}$$

for all $n$, and $0 \leq x - a < 1$. Let $n \to \infty$. Can you iterate this argument to show that $f$ is identically zero?

Comment: How very clever! Did you just invent this argument or is this a variation of a standard argument for such MVT problems? To iterate the argument, can we assume WLOG that $a$ is any element of $\frac 12 \mathbb Z$, so that $f$ is then identically zero? How do I explain this more rigorously?

Comment: I don't think I've seen an argument like this before. You can do some sort of induction to expand the interval on which $f$ is zero to the entire real line.

Comment: very smart and novel answer. I wish it was possible to vote up twice.